# ngrx 8 when dispatching action store is undefined

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have ngrx install on my angular 8 project. and when i dispacth action my store stay sill undefined

here is my code

```
 @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeadComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({ login : Reducer.reducer })
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ApiInterceptor, multi: true },],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

And

```
export const initialState: State = {
  logged : null
};

const loginReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(LoginAction.LOGIN, (state) => ({ ...state , logged : 1 })),
    on(LoginAction.LOGOUT , (state) =>  { console.log(state) ; const ret =  { ...state, logged : 0 } ; console.log( ret ); return ret })
)

export function reducer(state: State, action : Action) {
  loginReducer( state, action );
}
```

Here is the code where i trigger the action

```
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const request = req.clone({ url : environment.endpoint + req.url, setHeaders : {'Authorization':'Bearer '+ this.token.get()}});
        return next.handle(request).pipe( catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse, caught: Observable<HttpEvent<any>>) => {
            if( error && error.status === 401 ) {
                this.store.dispatch(Action.LOGOUT());
            }
            return throwError(error);
        }));
    }
```

here are my action

```
import { createAction} from "@ngrx/store";

export const LOGIN =    createAction('LOGIN');
export const LOGOUT =   createAction( 'LOGOUT' );
```

When the logout action is triggered, i can see a console log of my state that is

> { logged: 0 }

But when i subscripe

```
constructor( private http: HttpClient, private store : Store<Reducer.State>) {
        store.pipe(select('logged')).subscribe( elem => { console.log( elem )})

        http.get('/api/ping').subscribe(( data ) => {
            console.log( data );
        })


    }
```

I have got nothing in my log, could you help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logged does not exist on the global store state, but is a property of `login` (this is how you define it with `StoreModule.forRoot`), so you will have to do:

```
store.pipe(select('login', 'logged')).subscribe( elem => { console.log( elem )})
```

You will also have a return value from the reducer:

```
return  loginReducer( state, action );
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything in the result, and the  Ide accept only select('logged'), I think because I inject the withe private store: Store<interface{ logged : any }>

Comment: when id do select((store) => {console.log( store); return store.logged }) I have got an undefined in the log.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue, I forgot the return in the reducer definition !